# Vuejs Filter String Replace

Tags: string, vue.js

I have an image that i am binding the source to pull in dynamic data:

```
 <img :src="'/public/images/' + media.client.name + '_' + media.client.id + '/' + media.type + '/' + media.fileName + '.' + media.ext " alt >
```

The media.client.name returns a string that has %20 instead of spaces.

I have created a filter:

```
removeSpecial(value) {
  return value.replace("%20", " ");
}
```

How can I use this filter in the data binding of source please?

I have tried:

```
 <img :src="'/public/images/' + media.client.name | removeSpecial + '_' + media.client.id + '/' + media.type + '/' + media.fileName + '.' + media.ext " alt >
```

and

```
 <img :src="'/public/images/' + {{ media.client.name | removeSpecial }} + '_' + media.client.id + '/' + media.type + '/' + media.fileName + '.' + media.ext " alt >
```

Neither seem to work unfortunately.

Comment: Filters are not supported in attribute binding anymore. With that said, use [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) instead of find and replace. And for the specific purpose, instead of building url in line inside the binding expression, consider using a computed property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would depend on how you want to decode the URI component. If this `media` data is populated dynamically (I suppose so), you could make a method for parsing and decoding it (see example below). If you need this decoder as a `filter`, however, here's an excerpt from the docs:

> Filters **should be appended to the end of the JavaScript expression**, denoted by the "pipe" symbol.

So your best bet is probably to use a `computed` property so you can "pipe" it. And yes, you could utilize the native method [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) for this exact purpose.

### Approach #1: Method only

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      rootPath: '/public/images/',

      media: {
        client: {
          name: 'Music%20file%20with%20spaces',
          id: 123
        },
        type: 'music-file',
        fileName: 'some_music',
        ext: 'mp3'
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    getImgSource(media) {
      // Destructures the properties for improved readability.
      const { client, type, fileName, ext } = media;
      const { name, id } = client;
      
      // Uses template literals. Particularly useful for this situation
      // where you have several, unique delimiters.
      // Helps you see clearer how each of these URI components is combined.
      return `${this.rootPath}${decodeURIComponent(name)}_${id}/${type}/${fileName}.${ext}`;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <!-- Commented out for demo purposes, because I don't have the file.
  <img :src="getImgSource(media)" :alt="media.fileName" /> -->
  
  <!-- Let's assume this is an image element -->
  <div v-text="getImgSource(media)"></div>
</div>
```

### Approach #2: Computed property + filter

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      rootPath: '/public/images/',

      media: {
        client: {
          name: 'Music%20file%20with%20spaces',
          id: 123
        },
        type: 'music-file',
        fileName: 'some_music',
        ext: 'mp3'
      }
    }
  },

  computed: {
    mediaFile() {
      const { client, type, fileName, ext } = this.media;
      const { name, id } = client;
      
      return `${this.rootPath}${name}_${id}/${type}/${fileName}.${ext}`;
    }
  },
  
  filters: {
    decodeName: window.decodeURIComponent
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <!-- Let's assume this is an image element -->
  <div>{{ mediaFile | decodeName }}</div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is great. Thank you ever so much! This solution has worked in my project!

Comment: Glad it helped! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can make method which will return prepared url computed method like this:

```
imageUrl(media){
  return '/public/images/' + media.client.name.replace("%20", " ") + '_' + media.client.id + '/' + media.type + '/' + media.fileName + '.' + media.ext;
}
```

Or if media is assigned in data you can use computed method which will return you same url

```
computed: {
 imageUrl(){
  return '/public/images/' + this.media.client.name.replace("%20", " ") + '_' + this.media.client.id + '/' + this.media.type + '/' + this.media.fileName + '.' + media.ext;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much! This is great and a learning curve for me.